# Where are AWS CLI and SDK credentials actually stored? My computer disagrees with documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface, credentials

I effectively have a credential leak in my dev environment and can't plug the hole.

```
Windows 10  
Visual Studio Community 2017.  
AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio... 1.16.0.0  
aws-cli/1.17.15 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.14.15
```

I am aware of single sign on but have never attempted to use it. Access Key/Secret Key only.

I started with the documented storage locations existing. Perhaps created in earlier versions of the cli and studio extension? I then manually deleted `~/.aws` and the stumbled upon `~/appdata/local/awstoolkit` but I can just keep firing off CLI commands and editing in studio as if nothing changed. Using the `aws cli --no-sign-request` switch or using some other computer demonstrates the normal disposition of my reference commands is to require my credentials.

I've closed and reopened terminals, studio. I rebooted. Nothing cached, didn't matter. With those credential folders still not present, I can uninstall the AWS CLI and AWS SDK, reinstall them and without additional steps dive back into CLI commands and studio work without providing keys.

The only functional means to delete local credentials is to delete my profile within AWS's studio extension. With credentials deleted in that way, stuff stops working as it should. Using the AWS CLI configure command the CLI and studio will both be able to do credentialed work again but somehow without creating `~/.aws` or storing encrypted credentials in `~/appdata/local/awstoolkit`. I can use the `--debug` switch with AWS CLI commands to see that when they do succeed that the tool claims it finds my shared credentials at `~/.aws`.

While my credentials are working the expected files and folders do not exist. I cannot find the files or folders in Windows Explorer, PowerShell, or cmd.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The paths you mentioned are the main relevant ones for files, at least if you are talking about CLI access (there are some other options within an application). The one other place to look is in your environment variables.

I would recommend creating a new set of credentials and disabling (not deleting) the old one. At a minimum you can start working with the new credentials and be aware of where you put them. Then, if something isn't working, you can enable the old credentials for long enough to do what you need to do with them before trying to locate them once again.

Comment: For whatever reason the command line tool stores credentials as plain text and the storage location is obfuscated. This must be understood and managed prior to distributing back-end service rights to staff. My environment variables were inspected. Nothing related to AWS in my local user variables or global environment variables. I have admin rights to my machine. I can see from cli --debug that there are 9 different places the application looks and as noted the --debug output will state that the credentials are found at ~/.aws. That is verifiably false.